# Most secure way to process credit cards

Tags: coldfusion, credit-card, cfml

I am implementing credit card processing on my site and I am using a HTML form and processing the cards. I have only tested this for now. if some one view the source they can view the action page.

is there a way i can avoid this. is there a way to expire the page when user clicks the browser back button, so that he has to reload the page if he wants the view the previous page.

please explain the best practice. I am using coldfusion to make this form.

Comment: Best Practice questions are always going to be put on hold as too broad. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This question is not clear.  First, what's the big deal if the user can view the action page html source?  What is there that you want to hide from him?  Second, are you asking about clearing the form fields if the user goes back to it?

Comment: This question is too broad for stack overflow so I voted to close. A good starting point would be to search Google.  _Hint:_ you could even search for the title you gave this question and start getting answers. When you have specific code related questions to implementing then come back and ask on stack overflow. Another good source is OWASP - https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Handling_E-Commerce_Payments

Comment: downvoting, as the question is not clear and too broad in nature.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I would read the API for https://stripe.com/ and use them. They abstract all the processing card logic and make it super simple to process cards from your app.